# Is there a Java API to read, interpret, and write Java manifest files (MANIFEST.MF)?

Tags: java, api, manifest

I work with the ATG Dynamo platform - a Java based platform that uses manifest files to define many configuration details of its modules.

I would like to build some tools and scripts - say, ANT scripts or Maven plugins - to programmatically manipulate these files. Specifically, I want to be able to read existing files and perform some tasks based on the contents on one hand, and to generate new manifest files as part of my build process on the other.

The MANIFEST.MF format seems to be very simple, though there are some rules about line length and white space, so I am sure I can hand-code a lot of this. However, it would be really useful if there already exists an API to to read and write such files according to the spec.

Any suggestions?

Comment: atg manifest files are a bit different from java manifest files.  Did you get something going? I have similar goals and would love to start with something existing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JarFile#getManifest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getManifest%28%29). It gives you an instance of [`Manifest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html), providing several convenience methods to access the attributes.

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file);
Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
// ...
```

Comment: Perfect! It took me a while to realise that I could use JarFile even if my MANIFEST is not inside a JAR.

Comment: Correction: I believe I can use Manifest (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html#Manifest(java.io.InputStream)) class directly, without using JarFile

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer you may get some info from manifest through Package instance:

```
getClass().getPackage().getImplementationTitle(); // for example
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an API for reading/writing, but a utility class for reading all `MANIFEST.MF` files available in classpath: [jcabi-manifests](http://manifests.jcabi.com/index.html)

Also, see this post for more details: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/07/03/how-to-read-manifest-mf.html